# Sorting on a rank field

Tags: mdx

Why doesn't the following sort on a `rank` work? The actual ranking seems to be correct but for the life of me I cannot figure out why MDX doesn't sort it by the rank:

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Division Rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [Team].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember
     ,Order
      (
        Exists
        (
          [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].MEMBERS
         ,Descendants
          (
            [Team].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent
           ,1
          )
        )
       ,[Measures].[Wins]
       ,bdesc
      )
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    (
      [Season].[Season].[Season].[2019]
     ,{
        [Measures].[Wins]
       ,[Measures].[Division Rank]
      }
    )
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,{
    Order
    (
      [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].MEMBERS
     ,[Measures].[Division Rank]
     ,basc
    )
  } ON ROWS
FROM [Nfl2];
```

For example, why does the `2` occur before a `1` below?

[image]

---

UPDATE -- it should sort on `([Measures].[Wins], [Season].[Season].&[2019])` instead of just `[Measures].[Wins]`.

Answer (score 0):

Does adding the year into the order logic help?

```
WITH 
  MEMBER [Measures].[Division Rank] AS 
    Rank
    (
      [Team].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember
     ,Order
      (
        Exists
        (
          [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].MEMBERS
         ,Descendants
          (
            [Team].[Hierarchy].CurrentMember.Parent
           ,1
          )
        )
       ,[Measures].[Wins]
       ,bdesc
      )
    ) 
  SET [x] AS 
    Order
    (
      [Team].[Hierarchy].[Code].MEMBERS
     ,(
        [Measures].[Division Rank]
       ,[Season].[Season].[Season].[2019]
      )
     ,basc
    ) 
SELECT 
  {
    (
      [Season].[Season].[Season].[2019]
     ,{
        [Measures].[Wins]
       ,[Measures].[Division Rank]
      }
    )
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,[x] ON ROWS
FROM [Nfl2];
```